# Why Does my Keyframe Path Change?

Tags: keyframes

Im following CG cookies bouncing ball tutorial. I seem to understand everything thats being said except for one thing.

They're talking about deleting unnecessary keyframes on the X, and all we need is the Start point, its First Touch Point, and the End Point, and the rest of the keyframes can be deleted on the X.

The thing is when I delete my keyframes, my path totally changes, and I don't understand why at all, I thought I was following along exactly to the video. Whats going wrong?[image]

Comment: Its strange because I've don't this tutorial successfully before, and was only doing it again as a refresher but now it seems to be screwing up.

Comment: Ok for some reason when I delete my keyframes my graph seems to curve upward, I can add more pictures if needed.

Comment: never mind I guess my path was supposed to change and I just had to manipulate the curves. i didn't realize it would change so much though.

Comment: Instead of using comments, you can use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and modify or add to the original text.